# contentResolver doesn*t search recursively in subdirectories

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to search directories recursivly using a `contentResolver` and a `Cursor`.

```
c = resolver.query(childrenUri, null, null, null, null);
     while (c.moveToNext()) {
        final String documentId = c.getString(0);
        final Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(mUri,
                    documentId);
        results.add(documentUri);

}
```

childrenUri: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/document/downloads/children`

But I only get the documentURI from the files in the download folder and the documentUri of the subdirectory and not the documentUri of the documents in the subdirectory.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks 
Fischer Peter

Comment: I recommend using `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to take a document tree `Uri` and get an object on which you can `listFiles()` to get to sub-trees and documents in the tree.

Comment: is it so possible to get nested subdirectories and their documents?

Comment: You can do it the same way you would with `File`. With either `File` or `DocumentFile`, you would call `listFiles()` to find the contents of the tree. On each child, you would call `isDirectory()` to see if it is a sub-tree -- for those that are, use recursion (or whatever) to traverse downwards. Note that working with documents is a lot slower than is working with the filesystem, as a couple of rounds of IPC are needed for each request. I have notes about that [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/23/scoped-storage-stories-documentscontract.html).

Comment: Wondering why there isn't a faster way to get all files from a know tree in Android. I thought the content provider could provide such information...

Comment: My guess is that Google doesn't want you doing that. After all, I could create a `DocumentsProvider` for all of Wikipedia, and the user could choose some Wikipedia category as a "tree". While local content may be the most commonly-selected source of trees, do not assume that *only* local content will be used.

Comment: Yes, I'm with You. Now I have to do some coding….Thanks for the link on Your side. You did a good job with You blog...The link behind "Working with document trees" seems to be dead there

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the broken link! It is fixed now.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`. There is no recursion in your code. Dont blame the content resolver. You should implement recursion.

Comment: @blackapps  I thought Android would find all documents in tree for me

Comment: Of course not. Its no media store. And thats no tree.

Comment: Please continue with your code using DocumentsContract. Make it recursive. Dont use DocumentFile as it is twenty times slower than DocumentsContract. DocumentsContract is about as fast as the File class.

Comment: childrenUri seems to me to be a tree...How can I query `mediaStore` using `contentResolver`in Android 10 then?

Comment: You should determine a new children uri for every directory you get from the cursor. And treat that directory recursivly.